# Am I employing OOP correctly in Python while using tkinter and customtkinter?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, customtkinter

I am trying to make an application in Python using a combination of tkinter and customtkinter. Right now for the app, I just have a login page made and an account page made. So the only functionality I have so far is once valid creds are input on the login page, the user is taken to a page for their account.

I have a lot more experience in Java than Python (which is why I am trying this in Python, so I can actually learn more about it) so I really can't tell if the way I am writing my app is the correct way. I have made apps before with tkinter, but not while using classes too.

This is the code I have for the login page:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from accountPage import AccountPage  

class LoginPage:
    def __init__(self) -> None:   
        self.root = ctk.CTk()    

        ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue") 

        self.root.after(0, lambda:self.root.state('zoomed')) 
        self.root.title("Login Page") 

        bgImage = Image.open("bg.jpg")  
        bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bgImage) 
        bgLabel = tk.Label(self.root, image = bg)     
        bgLabel.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

        loginFrame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.root)     
        loginFrame.pack(pady = 120, padx = 500, fill = "both", expand = True)   

        loginLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(loginFrame, text = "Login", font = ("Tahoma", 35, "bold"))
        loginLabel.pack(pady = 30, padx = 10)

        self.usernameEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(loginFrame, placeholder_text="Username", font = ("Tahoma", 15), width = 300, height = 50)   
        self.usernameEntry.pack(pady = 30, padx = 10)

        self.passwordEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(loginFrame, placeholder_text="Password", show = "*", font = ("Tahoma", 15), width = 300, height = 50)   
        self.passwordEntry.pack(pady = 30, padx = 10) 

        loginButton = ctk.CTkButton(loginFrame, text="Login", font = ("Tahoma", 15, "bold"), command = self.validateLogin, width = 300, height = 50)  
        loginButton.pack(pady = 30, padx = 10)  

        self.root.mainloop()  



    def validateLogin(self) -> None: 

        name = self.usernameEntry.get().lower() 

        if self.checkProvidedLogin(name, self.passwordEntry.get()): 
              
            self.root.destroy()    
            AccountPage(name)

        else:

            messagebox.showerror(message = "Invalid login, Try again") 
    


    def checkProvidedLogin(self, username, password) -> bool:

        with open('logins.csv', 'r') as file:
                logins = file.read().splitlines()

        for line in logins:   
             if line == username + "," + password: 
                  return True

        return False  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    LoginPage()
```

And this is the code I have right now for the account page:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class AccountPage:
    def __init__(self, username) -> None: 
        self.accountRoot = ctk.CTk() 

        ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue") 

        self.accountRoot.after(0, lambda:self.accountRoot.state('zoomed')) 

        bgImage = Image.open("bg.jpg")  
        bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bgImage) 
        bgLabel = tk.Label(self.accountRoot, image = bg)    
        bgLabel.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1) 

        accountFrame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.accountRoot)
        accountFrame.pack(pady = 50, padx = 50, fill = "both", expand = True)   

        welcomeLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(accountFrame, text = f"Welcome, {username}!", font = ("Tahoma", 35, "bold"))
        welcomeLabel.pack(pady = 20)

        self.accountRoot.mainloop()
```

Again, it is working ok. Once valid creds are input, the account page appears. But I don't know if I am actually employing OOP correctly in combination with tkinter/customtkinter.

If anyone is willing to look through my code and provide any feedback it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Generally, you post a code review here: [Code Review Link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Although, the code at a glace looks good, maybe add the imports inside the function.

Comment: I wasn't tracking on the Code Review community. Thanks for letting me know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Description

So your good accomplishes your goal but its not quite good, I would suggest you to take a look at **customtkinters documentation** and specially check out the `OOP` section here's the link of `CTkWindow` and `CTkTopLevel` OOP code:

[CTkWindow OOP](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/windows/window)

[CTkTopLevel OOP](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/windows/toplevel)

### Improved Code:

Below is the good that works without errors as well as is optimised and good according to the documentation.

##### Code for Login Page:

```py
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from accountPage import AccountPage  

class LoginPage(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue") 

        self.after(0, lambda:self.state('zoomed')) 
        self.title("Login Page") 

        bgImage = Image.open("bg.jpg")  
        bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bgImage) 
        bgLabel = tk.Label(self, image = bg)     
        bgLabel.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

        loginFrame = ctk.CTkFrame(self)     
        loginFrame.pack(pady = 120, padx = 500, fill = "both", expand = True)   

        loginLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(loginFrame, text = "Login", font = ("Tahoma", 35, "bold"))
        loginLabel.pack(pady = 30, padx = 10)

        self.usernameEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(loginFrame, placeholder_text="Username", font = ("Tahoma", 15), width = 300, height = 50)   
        self.usernameEntry.pack(pady = 30, padx = 10)

        self.passwordEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(loginFrame, placeholder_text="Password", show = "*", font = ("Tahoma", 15), width = 300, height = 50)   
        self.passwordEntry.pack(pady = 30, padx = 10) 

        loginButton = ctk.CTkButton(loginFrame, text="Login", font = ("Tahoma", 15, "bold"), command = self.validateLogin, width = 300, height = 50)  
        loginButton.pack(pady = 30, padx = 10)
        
        self.toplevel_window = None 

    def validateLogin(self) -> None: 

        name = self.usernameEntry.get().lower() 

        if self.checkProvidedLogin(name, self.passwordEntry.get()): 
              
            self.withdraw()    
            self.toplevel_window = AccountPage(name)

        else:

            messagebox.showerror(message = "Invalid login, Try again") 
    
    def checkProvidedLogin(self, username, password) -> bool:

        with open('logins.csv', 'r') as file:
                logins = file.read().splitlines()

        for line in logins:   
             if line == username + "," + password: 
                  return True

        return False  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = LoginPage()
    root.mainloop()
```

##### Code for accountPage:

```py
import customtkinter as ctk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class AccountPage(ctk.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self, username, *args, **kwargs) -> None: 
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue") 

        self.after(0, lambda:self.state('zoomed')) 

        bgImage = Image.open("bg.jpg")  
        bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bgImage) 
        bgLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(self, image = bg)    
        bgLabel.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1) 

        accountFrame = ctk.CTkFrame(self)
        accountFrame.pack(pady = 50, padx = 50, fill = "both", expand = True)   

        welcomeLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(accountFrame, text = f"Welcome, {username}!", font = ("Tahoma", 35, "bold"))
        welcomeLabel.pack(pady = 20)

        self.mainloop()
```

### Note:

So if you observe your Login Page code you can see that you have called the `AccountPage` class after destroying the initial window this causes error in the interpreter as you are performing actions after the window that instantiates them is destroyed. It's not a good practice to do that instead make use of `TopLevel` or `Frame` to change between windows or scenes.
All you need to do is to go through the documentation it's really easy

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'll definitely check out the documentation then. Thanks a lot!